# Accessing Windows registry fails from ClickOnce application

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce, registry

here's another strange behaviour I'm currently facing. I have an application deployed on a network-drive with full-trust. This application checks for existing ODBC-Connections.

On my machine everything is fine and works as expected.

On the machine of a colleague it is not working and states the message, that he isn't able to access the key. In "regedit" he is able to access and change it. He's like me a local admin.

The Key the application is accessing is:

```
var odbcKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI");
```

Starting the same application with the *.exe everything is fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to edit the permission of this registry key by going to the registry key then right click on it, then permissions .. then give the user permission to read from it. ( assuming u are using windows 7 ).

I have faced the same problem, and it is fixed by giving the "write" permission for the correct user on this key, as you are trying to create a sub key in the registry which need permission.

Comment: As I said the user is local admin and is currently able to edit the key within regedit.

Comment: This is not enough, ok, try adding the user "everyone" and give it read and write permission and try and you will find that it will work.

Comment: ok... thanks... got it working. But this is quite strange even you are a local admin, you have to give explicit rights on the key to be able to change it in .net applications started from clickonce?

Comment: go to your registry key then right click on it, then click permissions then "Add" button..then type "Everyone" then click the "Ok" button ... then you will find the permissions checkboxes for this user..check the "Full Control" item under "Allow" column then click "ok" and try running ur app